# Better way of error handling?

Tags: php, class, error-handling

What are best way of error handling? This is what I came up with:

```
class test {

    public static function Payment($orderid, $total) {
        if (empty($orderid) && empty($total)) {
            return array('status' => 'fail', 'error' => 'Missing Data');
        }
    }

}
```

I heard about Try/Exceptions but how to fit that into my code? If you could provide example that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, use [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Specific to your example, you `throw` an exception if some condition fails. Then when you envoke the method that can throw an exception, you wrap it with a `try/catch` handling block.

```
class test {
  public static function Payment( $orderid, $total ) {
    if (empty( $orderid ) && empty( $total )) {
        throw new Exception('Missing Data');
    }
  }
}


try {
  test::Payment("1", "2"); //should be fine
  test::Payment(); //should throw exception
} catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e;
  //do other things if you need 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sample..  test::Payment("1", "2"); would be in the controller files. How would that work?

Comment: @user622378 Just place the entire try/catch block in your controller file then. I just placed it outside of the class to demonstrate it's usage.

Answer (score 5):

If you use PHP 5, you can handle error with exception :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

This way is cleaner than manual set exception message, because you have access to a try catch system and you can isolate exception handling

Answer (score 1):

[You could use exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

However, in the use case you've posted, simply doing the checks at the controller level should suffice.

I also think that explicitly checking the return type for array (on fail) is counter intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you might modify your code to use an exception.  It also helps to document the circumstances under which the exception is thrown.

```
class test {

    /**
     * [method description]
     * @throws Exception if the order ID or total is empty
     */
    public static function Payment($orderid, $total) {
        if (empty($orderid) && empty($total)) {
            throw new Exception("fail: Missing Data");
        }
    }

}
```

You can also create your own exception class if you want to include extra data in the exception.

```
class MyException extends Exception{
  public $status, $error;
  public function __construct($status, $error){
    parent::__construct("$status: $error");
    $this->status = $status;
    $this->error = $error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to lean towards throwing exceptions, and then using the try/catch mechanism to deal with the aftermath. The man page is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use Exceptions.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php